# What is the logic of the SPARQL CONSTRUCT LIMIT?

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, linked-data

What is the logic of LIMIT when using CONSTRUCT queries in SPARQL?

### When I use CONSTRUCT to query [DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql), I find that the results sometimes don't match the LIMIT

#### Example

SPARQL:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?s a ?sType .
  ?s ?p ?o .
  ?o a ?oType .
}
WHERE {
  GRAPH <http://dbpedia.org> {
    ?s a ?sType .
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?o a ?oType .
  }
}
LIMIT XXX
```

When limit = 3, result is incorrect:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/building> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#SpatialThing> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/building>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .
```

When limit = 10, result is incorrect:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/locationCountry>   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subPropertyOf>    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/locationCountry>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/building> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/locationCity>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/locationCity>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subPropertyOf>    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#SpatialThing> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Artifact100021939> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/locationCity>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/locationCountry>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Building102913152> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/building>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cabrini_Medical_Center>    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Hospital103540595> .
```

Comment: What is your definition of "incorrect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause applies to the `WHERE` clause.

With `LIMIT 3`, you will get at most 3 results from the `WHERE` clause. The `CONSTRUCT` clause will then work with only these 3 results, and produce as many triples as requested in the template.

Note that a *result* is not the same as a *triple*.

### Example

The `WHERE` clause has these **3 results**, thanks to your `LIMIT 3`:

| s | o | sType | p | oType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbr:Cabrini_Medical_Center | dbo:building | owl:Thing | rdf:type | rdf:Property |
| dbr:Cabrini_Medical_Center | dbo:building | dbo:building | rdf:type | rdf:Property |
| dbr:Cabrini_Medical_Center | dbo:building | geo:SpatialThing | rdf:type | rdf:Property |

These 3 results are derived from **4 triples**:

```
# ?s a ?sType . / ?s ?p ?o .
dbr:Cabrini_Medical_Center rdf:type dbo:building .
dbr:Cabrini_Medical_Center rdf:type owl:Thing .
dbr:Cabrini_Medical_Center rdf:type geo:SpatialThing .

# ?o a ?oType .
dbo:building rdf:type rdf:Property .
```

As your `CONSTRUCT` template is identical to the patterns in `WHERE`, these are also the produced triples.